# How to compare two array rows of same table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table like below:

```
empid  dept
-----  ----
1000   {acct,hr}
1005   {dev,hr}
```

where `dept` is a **text array**.

My requirement is to compare the rows in the table such that I can check whether column `dept` has any equal values or not. For example, in the above table it should compare
1000 - {hr} with 1005 - {hr} to give the similarity output as 1.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a strong advocate of representing this type of data using a junction/association table.  Usually, the SQL queries can be better optimized.

But given your data structure, you can generate all the pairs of employees and then count the departments where they are the same.  Assuming there are no duplicate departments for a given employee (as in your list):

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1000, array['acct', 'hr']), (1005, array['dev', hr'])) v(empid, depts)
     )
select t1.empid, t2.empid,
       (select count(*)
        from unnest(t1.depts) d1 join
             unnest(t2.depts) d2
             on d1 = d2
       ) cnt
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.empid < t2.empid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e8683d13fdb2beb354d69a9f1a79de05) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. What if  `dept` column has duplicates in it?

Comment: @ABeginner . . . Then you can use `count(distinct)` in the subquery.

Comment: Let's say the array is `array['acct', 'hr', 'hr']`  and `array['dev', 'hr', 'hr']`. Then it will show 1 as `count` if I use `distinct` but I was expecting it to give 2 as I just want to count the occurrence of same elements in two rows that have same elements in `dept` column.

Comment: @ABeginner . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question focused on how to handle duplicates.  As you've phrased this question, duplicates do not really  make sense -- employees either are or are not in a department.  If you modify this question, you are likely to invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: I will accept your answer for this question as I agree I didn't really phrase my question correctly :)